# Using fuse crate with macFuse installed

Tags: rust, fuse, rust-crates, macfuse

I am trying to implement a project which uses the rust crate `fuse` with the latest version which is "0.3.1", in my MacOS sonoma machine. I have `macfuse` installed which is the new version of `osxfuse` from what I have found.
When I try to build the project , I get the error :

```
  The system library `osxfuse` required by crate `fuse` was not found.
  The file `osxfuse.pc` needs to be installed and the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable must contain its parent directory.
  The PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable is not set.

  HINT: if you have installed the library, try setting PKG_CONFIG_PATH to the directory containing `osxfuse.pc`.

  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I tried setting the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` env manually to `/Library/Frameworks/macFUSE.framework` , but it gives the error :

```
The system library `osxfuse` required by crate `fuse` was not found.
  The file `osxfuse.pc` needs to be installed and the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable must contain its parent directory.
  PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains the following:
      - /Library/Frameworks/macFUSE.framework

  HINT: you may need to install a package such as osxfuse, osxfuse-dev or osxfuse-devel.
```

I have tried searching the web but couldn't find much help.